# connection refused exception when trying to run a jar via web start

Tags: java

I am getting the following exception when trying to run my jar through java web start:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost   /ValidatorWEB/validator.jnlp
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
```

This is the wrapped exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my .jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/ValidatorWEB/" 
href="validator.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Validator</title>
    <vendor>My Company</vendor>
</information>
<resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <j2se version="1.6+"
          href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="WEB-INF/lib/validator.jar" main="true" />

</resources>
<application-desc
     name="Validator"
     main-class="webstartComponentArch.DynamicTreeApplication"
     width="300"
     height="300">
 </application-desc>
 <update check="background"/>
```

I am deploying the whole thing as a simple WAR to glassfish v2.1 on my *local machine*. The validator.jar is located in WEB-INF/lib and the jnlp and jsp page I am accessing the jnlp from is at the root of the ValidatorWEB folder.

Googling hasn't helped. I have tried turning my firewall off and it still does the same thing. I have the appropriate Mime-type set in Glassfish. Is there something else I'm forgetting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem was where I am specifying the base url:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost/ValidatorWEB/" href="validator.jnlp">
```

When I deployed to Glassfish, the url that I would access the web application through is actually:

```
http://localhost:8080/ValidatorWEB/
```

I had to change my codebase to read:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/ValidatorWEB/" href="validator.jnlp">
```

This is something I will definitely have to keep in mind when deploying to a remote server.

Thanks for all of the input!

Comment: I believe there is a servlet thing from Sun that can generate the correct JNLP for a given deployment.

Answer (score 1):

You do know what `http://localhost` actually points to? It points to the web server which is running at **localhost** at port 80. Localhost == 127.0.0.1 == local machine.

As Webstart aka JNLP apps runs at the *client* machine, it will try to connect the web server at the *same* (local) machine. You don't want to do that. Change the URL to point to the actual web server at the *server* machine where your webapp runs and where JNLP is to be downloaded from.

Comment: I am trying to run it from localhost. I am not currently deploying to a seperate machine.

Answer (score 0):

How about the policy file? See here: http://blogs.oracle.com/monzillo/entry/policy_files_the_securitymanager_and

Comment: I'm not familiar with that at all. I did a quick google on it, but didn't find anything that references policies and web start. Can you be a bit more specific as to what I should verify is there or not?

Comment: Look for this file:
$J2EE_HOME/domains/domainx/config/server.policy
and set its content to
grant {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
}

This is just for testing!! If this helps, you're on the right track and should read the link in my original post and this one: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

The spaces after `localhost` make me suspicious - is there a chance you've defined the hostname with trailing spaces somewhere and web start isn't having any of it?

Also, have you tried simply `wget`ting (or similar) the listed jnlp URL?  The response from the request will let you see what's happening when Java makes the same request.

Comment: There aren't any spaces after localhost. Not that I see in the editor.

Comment: Spaces look like an artifact of the terminal line wrapping to me.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if its related but while giving address of resource jar, i would not use "WEB-ıNF/lib", client machine cannot see inside web-inf, you should put that jar inside web application not inside web-inf.

Comment: That wasn't the problem, but I did have to move the validator.jar to the same place as my .jnlp file. I couldn't get it to access the resource correctly while it was in the WEB-INF/lib folder.